# How to install yED graphic editor?

Tags: software-installation, yed

I am trying to download and run [yED - Graph Editor](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed), I have downloaded `Yed-3.14.3_64bit_setup.sh`, but I am lost on what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete procedure to install yED graphic editor. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
wget https://www.yworks.com/products/yed/demo/yEd-3.14.4_64-bit_setup.sh
chmod +x yEd-3.14.4_64-bit_setup.sh
sudo -H ./yEd-3.14.4_64-bit_setup.sh
```